# Display more search results of API with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

first to all i'm new in Javascript, Ajax, jQuery, JSON and the dev world. I'm working on a web project that I want to display search results from a Google Books API. Currently I made the code that display just 1 result and it worked fine, but I see in console.log that the API shows me an array of 10 more items as a result and I would like to display them. I would like to display all of this results but I don't know how to do this.
I have a DIV in my HTML code and this is my Ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: API + libroBuscado,
    success: function(data) {


  var componente = `<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4> 
      <h4 class="precio">$</h4>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Descarga un adelanto</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Comprar</a>

    </div>
  </div>`;

  var titulo = data.items[0].volumeInfo.title;
  var venta = data.items[0].saleInfo.saleability;
  var precio = "ARS $" + data.items[0].saleInfo.listPrice.amount;
  var autor = data.items[0].volumeInfo.authors;
  var sinopsis = data.items[0].volumeInfo.description;
  var descarga = data.items[0].accessInfo.webReaderLink;
  var compra = data.items[0].saleInfo.buyLink;

  $(".col-12").html(componente);
  $(".card-title").text(titulo);
  $(".precio").text(precio);
  $(".card-subtitle").text(autor);
  $(".card-text").text(sinopsis);
  $(".card-link:nth-of-type(0)").attr("href" + descarga);
  $(".card-link:nth-of-type(1)").attr("href" + compra);
  console.log(data);
},

error: function(error) {
  console.log(error);
}


 });
});
```

I was thinking make a for loop but I don't know how to do it or if it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to loop through them instead of just calling for item at index 0.

Something like this.

```
var titulo;
var venta;
var precio;
var autor;
var sinopsis;
var descarga;
var compra;

for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) { 
    titulo = data.items[i].volumeInfo.title;
    venta = data.items[i].saleInfo.saleability;
    precio = "ARS $" + data.items[i].saleInfo.listPrice.amount;
    autor = data.items[i].volumeInfo.authors;
    sinopsis = data.items[i].volumeInfo.description;
    descarga = data.items[i].accessInfo.webReaderLink;
    compra = data.items[i].saleInfo.buyLink;
}
```